# Insert Current/Sysdate in XML Tag

Tags: xml, date, xslt

I am trying to insert current date value in the XML tag using XSL.

**DateValue.xml**

```
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
....
.....
</ROW>
</ROSWET>
```

**Expected Result:**
Note the ROW tag description to include Date Value.

```
<ROWSET>
<ROW Version="0.8" CreationDateAndTime = "2015-05-04T15:15:51.0">
....
.....
</ROW>
</ROSWET>
```

Please, advice!

Thanks,
Carthyc

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 will try XSLT 2.0 if the coding in 1.0 is tricky.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 this is trivial. In XSLT 1.0, it depends on which XSLT 1.0 processor you are using.